# How to convert array to QString?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I use QString::number() to convert float[4] to QString, but I see an error:

`call of overloaded 'number(float [4])' is ambiguous`

Comment: You can only convert one single value to string, not an array.

Comment: Okay( Then i should ask -
How to display float[4] via textEdit ?

Comment: You need to provide more information. _How_ do you want these floats displayed textually? What sort of floating point precision do you need?

Comment: Actually I am not excited by the form of display or precision, I simply want to display it via QTextEdit or other widget in Qt cteator.

Answer (score 1):

`QString::number` has various overloads:

```
QString number(long n, int base = 10)
QString number(double n, char format = 'g', int precision = 6)
QString number(ulong n, int base = 10)
QString number(int n, int base = 10)
QString number(uint n, int base = 10)
QString number(qlonglong n, int base = 10)
QString number(qulonglong n, int base = 10)
```

Your compiler is trying to convert the array to a pointer and the pointer to an integer. Since it can convert the pointer to more than one integer type for which there is an overload, it cannot decide which overload to use.

Did you mean to use the array in the call to `QString::number` or just one of the elements of the array?

Comment: I use array, not a single element of this array

Comment: That's the problem. There is no overload of `QString::number` that can work with an array. To convert the entire array to `QString`, you'll have to convert each element of the array, decide what separator to use to combine them, and combine the resulting strings in a loop.

Comment: Yep, I understood.I can display somehow float via textEdit?

Comment: Hmm. QTextEdit — is a visual element of the graphic interface in QT Creator.

Comment: @Nickel94, I have never used `QTextEdit`. I can't help you there.

Comment: Like R Sahu, said, iterate the array of floats and convert each float to a QString using QString::number(). Concatenate the converted strings with a separator of your choice. Set the QTextEdits contents to the resulting string using QTextEdit::setPlainText(). If it's not clear to you what to do after this, I think you simply have to study some more C++, read the Qt documentation, and most importantly, learn by practicing!

Comment: Thank you. Practice is that I do now